# Php news page - news.php?article1

Tags: php, ajax, article

Could someone help me out? I would like to simplify my life by providing a news page where I can simply have a template php doc with a blank content area that is filled by data from my news article. Rather than making a new page for every article I publish, I would like to be able to click a link that fills in the data from another php file with the article in.

By this I mean so the domain is something like this:

> domain.com/news.php?article1

rather

> than /news/article1.php

How can I go about this or where shall I go to read up about something like this. I was thinking of heading to a cms, however taking the time to learn to template my website just for one news page to regularly update seems a little too much effort than it's worth.

I would rather not have to create a new page every time I add an article. I would simply just like to add a new template php file, that I can call upon to display the relevant information on a common news page.

My problem is, I am learning at this moment and I do not know where to start.

Any advice will be more than welcome! Thank you.

Comment: I believe this [link](http://www.html.net/tutorials/php/lesson10.php) is what you are looking for. Just a beginner tut.

Answer (score 2):

link format : domain.com/news.php?article=1

```
$articleNum = $_GET["article"];

//get that article
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Giving a detailed answer will make your answer more appropriate and more eligible for `upvotes` and `accepted answer`. So, be descriptive in your answers. All the best :)